# Pass JSON Values to select tag (Ionic Framework)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Iam trying to pass the a json response to a HTML select tag in Ionic , But in this process iam Receiving the following error , when i try to push the values to select tag. From the Below jSON Response i need to pass the only the Location field as well.

**JSON Response**

[image]

**Error**

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'String'.   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type
>   'String': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 39 more.

```
 <ion-select id="atm" placeholder="Selected ATM">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let atm of atms" value="{{ atm.id }}">{{ atm.location }}
      </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

const newheadersNew = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': window.sessionStorage.getItem("auth")

};


this.nativeHttp.get('https://'myapi.com/getall', {}, newheadersNew)
    .then(data => {


        let atm = JSON.parse(data.data);
        this.atms = [];

        const values = Object.values(atm);
        console.log(values);

        for (const value of values) {

            this.atms.push(value);

        }

        this.dismiss();


    })
    .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `let atm = JSON.parse(data.data);` is the array of objects in your image and to push them to a class property you can just do

```
this.atm = [...atm];
```

This spread operator pulls out each object and in the end, you get a copy of your atm variable.

If you only want to pass the location:

```
this.atm = atm.map({location} => ({location}));
```

In your select tag:

```
<select>
 <option *ngFor="let option of atm">{{ option.location }}</option>
</select>
```

The problem with your code:

```
const values = Object.values(atm);
```

you should pass an object to `Object.values` not an array of objects.

**UPDATE**:
So now your http call should be like:

```
this.nativeHttp.get('https://'myapi.com/getall', {}, newheadersNew)
    .then(data => {
        this.atms = [...JSON.parse(data.data)];
        this.dismiss();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
Can you share a complete HTTP Call referencing my above example,
A great help

Comment: Thank you , i will a try Still iam facing the error Specially i need to obtain the location from the returning data set and needs to show in the ionic select tag..

Comment: Values were not populating to select tag..  (Response was successful from get request)

Comment: Task completed . Thanks